# Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: javascript

Вот код

```
var aaa = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
alert("Всего картинок" + aaa.length);
```

По идеи у меня должно выходить Всего картинок как бы в рамке,а у меня какие е то символы и др.

Comment: console.log(aaa.length);

Comment: у меня в хроме 33 работает и выдает ожидаемый результат.

какой браузер, какой версии, как пытаетесь выполнить код?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно дело в используемой кодировке.
Проверьте что в атрибуте charset тега meta указана нужная вам кодировка, и что она соответствует кодировке самого документа.